# Activate doom mode line theme on non doom theme

Tags: themes, mode-line, gui-emacs, doom

I would like to use a non doom theme on Emacs but I like the doom mode line.  The problem is if I use a non doom dark theme, say Charcoal-Black, and activate doom mode line, then doom mode line is always in light color, very hard to see.

It seems that doom themes are made for doom mode line.  So if I have Doom Dracula, then doom mode line will automatically adjust to have theme similar to Doom Dracula.

So, I would like to know if:

- Can we customize doom mode line face if we are using a non doom theme? Eg, background, foreground.
- On the other hand, can I use a non doom theme like Charcoal Black, then somehow tells doom mode line to use say Doom Dracula as its theme for the mode line?

This is an example of what I meant[image]

As you can see, the doom modeline background is always white on non doom theme.

Comment: The answer is "yes".  But I'm pretty sure that wouldn't be satisfactory.  So please, rewrite your question to clarify what you want to know.  It would probably also help if you gave concrete examples of the themes and the mode-lines in which you're interested.

Comment: I just rewrote the question

Comment: I'm using doom-modeline with zenburn theme without issues so far (or your issues). I just load the modeline _after_ the theme.

Comment: I added a picture to show what I meant.